# How to unlist glm summaries into date frames

Tags: r, list, glm, summary

Let's consider list of summaries:

```
set.seed(42)
bin_var <- sample(0:1, 125, T)
indep_1 <- rnorm(125)
indep_2 <- rexp(125)
indep_3 <- runif(125)

summary_list <- list(summary(glm(bin_var~indep_1)),
                     summary(glm(bin_var~indep_2)),
                     summary(glm(bin_var~indep_3)))
```

What I want to end up with is identical list containing those summaries but each in data frame format.

To convert summary.glm into data frame we just need to use:

```
summary_list[[1]]$coefficients
```

So my idea was to use:

```
lapply(summary_list,"$", "coefficients")
```

But it gives only NULLs. Do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function :

```
result <- lapply(summary_list,function(x) x$coefficients)
```

Or using `[[` is similar to `$`.

```
result <- lapply(summary_list, `[[`, 'coefficients')
```

If you want everything on one dataframe use `do.call(rbind, result)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be the following:

```
do.call('rbind', 
        lapply(seq_len(length(summary_list)), 
               function(i) coefficients(summary_list[[i]])))
```

which yields:

```
# Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.56664011 0.04473468 12.6666853 4.779611e-24
# indep_1     -0.01879638 0.04246236 -0.4426597 6.587894e-01
# (Intercept)  0.58719761 0.06862352  8.5567986 3.891567e-14
# indep_2     -0.01719474 0.04668204 -0.3683373 7.132549e-01
# (Intercept)  0.39294331 0.09647586  4.0729705 8.253436e-05
# indep_3      0.34647724 0.17000447  2.0380478 4.368955e-02
```